# ¿Por qué arroja el error Cannot access 'cliente' before initialization at HTMLFormElement?

Tags: javascript, formularios, eventos, dom, listener

Al intentar correr el código por consola lanza un error que dice "Cannot access 'cliente' before initialization at HTMLFormElement" justo en la línea 16 donde está el idForm pero no sé si el origen del fallo está en esa línea o más abajo de no poder accesar al formData.

```
let clientes = []

class Cliente {
   constructor(nombre, apellido, edad, ingresos) {
      this.nombre = nombre;
      this.apellido = apellido;
      this.edad = edad;
      this.ingresos = ingresos;
   }
}

document.getElementById("linkA").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
   e.preventDefault()
})

divClientes = document.getElementById("divClientes")

document.getElementById("idForm").addEventListener("submit", function(e) {
   e.preventDefault()
   console.log(e.target)

   let datosFormulario = new FormData(e.target)

   const cliente = new cliente(datosFormulario.get("nombreC"), datosFormulario.get("apellidoC"), datosFormulario.get("edadC"), datosFormulario.get("ingresosC"))
   console.log(cliente)
   clientes.push(cliente)
   localStorage.setItem("clientes", JSON.stringify(clientes))
   document.getElementById("idForm").reset();
})

document.getElementById("mostrarCliente").addEventListener("click", function() {
   
   let clientes = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("clientes"))
   console.log(clientes)
   for(cliente of clientes) {

      divClientes.innerHTML += 
      `
         <div>
            <p> Nombre: ${cliente.nombre} </p>
            <p> Apellido: ${cliente.apellido} </p>
            <p> Edad: ${cliente.edad} </p>
            <p> Ingresos: ${cliente.ingresos} </p>
         </div>
      `
   }

})



<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="" id="idForm">
    <label for="Nombre">Nombre Cliente</label>
    <input type="text" id="nombreC" name="nombreC">
    <label for="Apellido">Apellido Cliente</label>
    <input type="text" id="apellidoC" name="apellidoC">
    <label for="Edad">Edad Cliente</label>
    <input type="text" id="edadC" name="edadC">
    <label for="Ingresos">Ingresos Cliente</label>
    <input type="text" id="ingresosC" name="ingresosC">
    <input type="submit" value="Enviar">
    </form>
    <button id="mostrarCliente">Mostrar Clientes</button>
    <div id="divClientes"></div>
    <a href="https://www.google.com.ar/?gws_rd=ssl" id="linkA">x</a>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Estás tratando de usar la Clase `Cliente`, pero has escrito el nombre de la misma en minúsculas: `const cliente = new cliente( ... );`. Debes usar: `const cliente = new Cliente( ... );`. Corrige ese problema y comenta el resultado. Saludos

Comment: Es correcto @MauricioContreras. Justo ese era el error. Veo que ahora no me funciona el botón de eliminar los clientes, pero allí probaré de nuevo para ver qué pasa... Saludos